# Sequelize: M2M Filter entities that don't have a tag out

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a many to many relationship between tags and stories in my database. I would like to filter the stories by those with a specific tag, however I would like to include all the tags of a story in the result set. How would I go about this?

Right now, my query is returning only one tag(the tag being used as the filter) with each story. I want it to include all of the tags of given story.

[image: Relation]

This is my current query.

```javascript
        models.Story.findAll({
            attributes: ['id', 'title', 'description'],
            include: [
                {
                    attributes: ['name', 'description'],
                    model: models.Tag,
                    where: {
                        id: tag.id
                    },
                    order: [['useCount', 'desc']]
                },
                {
                    attributes: ['id', 'displayName'],
                    model: models.User,
                    where: {
                        id: models.sequelize.col('User.id')
                    }
                }
            ]
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your relations are modeled as

```
models.users.hasMany(models.stories);

models.stories.belongsTo(models.users);
models.stories.belongsToMany(models.tags, {
    through: 'story_tags'
});
models.stories.hasMany(models.story_tags);

models.tags.belongsToMany(models.stories, {
    through: 'story_tags'
});
models.tags.hasMany(models.story_tags);

models.story_tags.belongsTo(models.stories);
models.story_tags.belongsTo(models.tags);
```

Then here's what you could do:

```
models.stories.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'title', 'description'],
    include: [{
        model: models.tags,
        attributes: ['id'],
        where: {
            id: tag.id
        }
    }, {
        model: models.users,
        attributes: ['id', 'displayName'],
        where: {
            id: {
                $col: 'user.id'
            }
        }
    }, {
        model: models.story_tags,
        attributes: ['id'],
        include: [{
            model: models.tags,
            attributes: ['name', 'description']
        }]
    }]
}).then(stories => {
    // The rest of your logics here...
});
```